# Find text in one column, if true then match the text in the column next to it with a column on a separate sheet and insert a formula

Tags: excel, vba

Here's what I have:

[Response Flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oke6Q.png)

I have one sheet called Response Flow that has Response, Y/N and a Total. If the Response has a Y next to it I want to match the Response Name with the Response Name on Sheet 2 ("Campaigns") and insert a formula in the column next to the response name on Sheet 2 using VBA code. Below is what I have so far.

```
Sub Volume_Calc()

Dim LastRowR As Long
Dim LastRowC As Long
Dim LastRowI As Long
Dim LastRowA As Long
Dim rngFoundCell As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim text As String
Dim FindRow As Range

LastRowR = Range("C65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowC = Range("K65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowI = Range("I65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastRowA = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

Set FindRow = Worksheets("ResponseFlow").Range("C:C").Find(What:="Y", 
LookIn:=xlValues)

Do While FindRow = True
If Application.Match(Worksheets("Campaigns").Range("K6"), 
Worksheets("ResponseFlow").Range("A4:A" & LastRowA), 0) Then
Worksheets("Campaigns").Range("I6:I" & LastRowI).Formula = "=INDEX(ResponseFlow!$B$3:$B$145,MATCH(Campaigns!$K6,ResponseFlow!$A$3:$A$145,0))" 
End If
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Why does this have to be VBA?  This could be done with a countifs and a vlookup (or just a vlookup)

Comment: The reason it must be in VBA is because this will be attached to a button within the spread sheet.

Comment: ok.... why does it need to be attached to a button?  Here's the formula.  Put this in sheet "Campaigns" cell i6 and copy down: `=IF(COUNTIFS(ResponseFlow!$A:$A,$K6,ResponseFlow!$B:$B,"Y")=0,"",VLOOKUP($K6,ResponseFlow!$A:$B,2,FALSE))`

Comment: Or even better, because the COUNTIFS already verifies name and corresponding Y response, no need for a VLOOKUP, so formula can be simplified to: `=IF(COUNTIFS(ResponseFlow!$A:$A,$K7,ResponseFlow!$B:$B,"Y")=0,"","Y")`

Comment: Or create a drop down cell "button" (which is really data validation) that just essentially does "on" or "off" for in if-statement for all the COUNTIF VLOOKUP cells

Comment: Hi All sorry I should have explained a little better. On the campaigns sheet there will be a Response column and a Total column with totals in it. This sheet is going to be used by external users so I only want the formula inserted in the cells within the total column where the corresponding Response Name matches with the response name on the Response Flow sheet and where there is a Y. They also have the ability to change a Y to a N so if they change it to an N then it shouldn't pick up that row when they hit the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're intending to do seems like it'd be easier to do in Excel without VBA, but if you insist on having some macro insert formulas, this might be an easy approach. First put the dynamic formula you want to be pasting in to the right of the columns with a Y/N, SOMEWHERE in your sheet. In my example below I used Cell("Z1"). Make sure it's dynamic so that if you were to copy/paste formula into another cell, it would adjust correctly.

Again make sure whatever dynamic match formula you want to the right of your values is somewhere and configured to be dynamic. In my example it's on Response ws in cell Z1.

```
Sub Volume_Calc()

Dim Resp_WS As Worksheet: Set Resp_WS = Worksheets("ResponseFlow")
Dim CAMP_WS As Worksheet: Set CAMP_WS = Worksheets("Campaigns")

Dim rCell As Range
Dim cCell As Range

'Loops through Response Sheeet column "C" looking for values of "Y"
For Each rCell In Intersect(Resp_WS.Range("C:C"), WResp_WS.UsedRange).Cells
    If UCase(rCell.Value) = "Y" Then

        'When finds a cell with Y, it then loops through Campaigns Sheet column "I"
        'looking for a value that matches one column to the left where the "Y" was found
        For Each cCell In Intersect(CAMP_WS.UsedRange, CAMP_WS.Range("I:I")).Cells

            'When match is found, the macro will insert the formula to the right
            'of the cell in Campaigns, with the dynamically updated formula in cell Z1
            If cCell.Value = rCell.offset(0,-1).Value Then
                cCell.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = Resp_WS.Range("Z1").FormulaR1C1
            End If
        Next cCell
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks but this is not matching the Response Name with the Response Name on the Campaigns sheet. I need the formula to be inserted in the Totals column on the Campaigns sheet.

Comment: @JonezyMeszaros take a look now. Please accept answer if that works. Thanks.

Comment: Actually think I need another offset for the value in there. It's set to equal Y. Using your example from the screen image, should we loop through column B, then check the next sheet what's in column A?

Comment: Hi PGCodeRider that did not work. It copied the formula to every Response name and not just the ones where there was a Y. Ultimately I need it to look for a Y then look at the response name find it on the Campaigns tab and change the total for that response name that has a Y to the total on the response tab.

Comment: @JonezyMeszaros take look now. I included comments to carefully explain what it's doing. Again, please mark as complete as I've put about 15 minutes into this now. If there's something that you don't understand or not working please articulate. I do hope this helps you understand! I know VBA can be tough at first.

Comment: You sir are the man!! So now I'm just having one more small small issue.... When it copies the formula over it changes Campaigns!$K6 (in the formula below) to Campaigns!$K11 for some strange reason. Any idea? =INDEX(ResponseFlow!$B$3:$B$145,MATCH(Campaigns!$K6,ResponseFlow!$A$3:$A$145,0))

Comment: Thanks @JonezyMeszaros. That's a reference reason. A better way to to figure out what you want, get the formula accurate in a position you're GOING to have the macro paste into, then paste THAT formula into Z1. I don't know the nature of your formula, but the K6 is really a reference of "+x rows lower"  or "-1 rows to go higher". If you research R1C1 formulas, it might make more sense. Best of luck and thanks for the check!